# Newly created layout files not added to R.java

Tags: android, layout

I have tried literally everything to figure out why no new layout files are being added to my R.java file in eclipse.  Nothing is working.

I have:

- Restarted Eclipse
- Used Project>Clean
- Deleted R.java (had to restore because it would not autoregenerate no matter what I did)
- Ensured all methods are defined in SDK version
- Rebuilt the project
- Unchecked auto-build
- Every combination of above options
- Been tempted to throw my computer across the room

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that your Eclipse project is an Android project (not Java)? Have you tried to fix the Android project properties via Right Click on project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties?

Comment: I did all of this as well.  And I am positive it is an android project.

Comment: Make sure there are no errors in the layout files. Choose clean from the Project menu.

Comment: Does any file in res/* dirs have hyphen (i.e. my-pic.jpg) in their name?

Comment: As I said, I already used Clean.  It did nothing.  There are no hyphens in any of the layout file names.

Comment: What I understand is that you are unable to add any new layout to your res folder. Whenever you try adding your R.java is not generated. Can you tell me what happens when you remove your newly added layout. If the problem is resolved after removing then please paste that layout here so that we can examine it.

Comment: In the past when I've had problems with resources building themselfs, I've always had an error message like "[2012-11-20 11:21:41 - ADR_MobileCPO] res\layout\Mmain.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]" in the console window of eclipse.  Errors will get printed to the console each time a change is made to any resource file

Comment: Go to the problems in the show view and clean the previous problems and then clean your project and see the problem again. Please let me know what it says then. May be i can give you a suggestion after that.

Comment: you say that one of the things you tried was "Unchecked auto-build". For me, that is usually what causes this problem. Perhaps make sure it is checked as in Artyom Kiriliyk's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Check you don't have any errors *inside* one of your xml files. That is, check not only for xml file name errors but also for errors in the xml code, for example an illegal attribute, a forgotten tag etc. Check this in all your xml files, not just layout files but also anim, xml drawables etc. These errors don't show up in the error log but will prevent the R.java from being generated.

When I experienced the same issue as you this was often the reason. The error highlight was only visible inside the file, not the error log.

Net, go through every xml file with a fine comb.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this kind of problem many times. From my thoughts it is caused due to the problem of images in the drawable or case sensitive of layout file (everything should be small). Check your case sensitive of layout file.

Comment: There aren't any drawables in the two layout files that I want to utilize.  One is a very simple textview and the other is a gridview.  I've reduced all attributes to only the necessary layout_width and layout_height and id.

Comment: What about layout file name (case sensitive)

Comment: File names are all lowercase so there is no confusion.

Comment: check whether it starts with a a numerical?

Comment: Same issue solved here by changing the images name to lowercase. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

I will give all possible solutions that i had done when something like this happened with me

1. Project-->clean
2. Check for library if there was any for that
       RightClick-->Properties-->Android-->add
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Check in
       the manifest for if you have many packages make sure u are using the
       activity declared package.

Answer (score 3):

I would check the imported `R`. The problem could be that you have

```
import android.R;
```

instead of

```
import com.myproject.R;
```

Answer (score 2):

Project -> and check Build Automatically

Comment: yes, this problem began for me when I unchecked Build Automatically. This is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any error in your resource files? If there is any error in your resource files the R file will not be generated.

Answer (score 1):

When first of u go on Project->Clean the your application then refreshing and auto genrated R.java file for your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be repetitive, but did you check the Android manifest file? The error there doesn't usually pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check for other locale letters (maybe whitespaces too?) in the filenames? Letters that look exactly like Latin.
I think I had similar problem with the names. You can try rewriting your files' names.

Answer (score 1):

Project Explorer (Right click on your project) -> Build Project
This worked for me.